# Angular Deferrable Views causing call stack issue

Tags: angular

This suddently became an issue today after upgrading to Angular 17.3

This works no problem. It loads 3 separate components. 2 pre-defined, 1 depending on the url route.

```
 @if(!hasErrorSignal()){

    <!-- app header bar -->
    <app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>

    <!-- project navigation menu -->
    <app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>

    <!-- project page router -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  } @else {

    <p>Error in making Http request(s).</p>

  }
```

This however causes a massive call stack issue, and the page seems to load app header and navigation menu components 100+ times, until the call stack is exceeded.

```
@defer(when isDataLoaded) {

  @if(!hasErrorSignal()){

    <!-- app header bar -->
    <app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>

    <!-- project navigation menu -->
    <app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>

    <!-- project page router -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  } @else {

    <p>Error in making Http request(s).</p>

  }

} @placeholder {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Initialising data fetch...</p>
  </div>

} @loading (minimum 250ms) {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  </div>

} @error {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Something went wrong!</p>
  </div>

}
```

isDataLoaded is just a simple boolean, that is set to false initially in the component, and once a API call is complete, then set to true...

This wasn't a problem yesterday with Angular 17.1. Am I missing something really simple. The other thing is, with the 2nd code, all the routerlink urls lose the relative link references, and just reference from the app root.

**Here is the full error:**

```
core.mjs:6531 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3043:5)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3093:33)
    at lookupTokenUsingEmbeddedInjector (core.mjs:6155:72)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:5766:43)
    at NodeInjector.get (core.mjs:6072:16)
    at OutletInjector.get (router.mjs:2544:24)
    at ChainedInjector.get (core.mjs:15668:37)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:5730:39)
```

Comment: could you provide minimal a stackblitz repro of this issue ?

Comment: I've provided the full component code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78216445/angular-ngoninit-running-multipe-times-resulting-in-call-stack-error-with-sign?noredirect=1#comment137895082_78216445