# Angular NgOnInit running multipe times, resulting in call stack error, with Signals

Tags: angular

Is this normal behaviour? I'm getting this with Angular 17.3

getProject is an aynchronous function that sets the projectSignal variable to project ID. But the ngOnInit is executing the if branch, and then later also the else branch, and then keeps executing the else branch 100+ times until there is a call stack failure. Shouldn't it just execute the if, or else branch just once? This wasn't an issue with Angular 17.0

**Here is the full code of the component class:**

```
/***** Angular Imports *****/
import { Component, inject, Signal } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
/***** RxJS Imports *****/
import { Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
/***** Services Imports *****/
import { SpringAPIService } from '../../services/spring-api/spring-api.service';
import { APIErrorService } from '../../services/api-error/api-error.service';
import { ProjectService } from '../../services/project-service/project.service';
/***** Child Component Imports *****/
import { AppHeaderComponent } from '../../top-navigation/app-header/app-header.component';
import { ProjectNavigationComponent } from '../../top-navigation/project-navigation/project-navigation.component';
import { ProjectDetailComponent } from '../project-detail/project-detail.component'
/***** Data Transfer Object (DTO) Imports *****/
import { AnyProjectDTO } from '../../services/dto-service/dtos/ProjectDTO'

/**********************************************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************** COMPONENT ******************************************************/
/**********************************************************************************************************************/

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, AppHeaderComponent, ProjectNavigationComponent, ProjectDetailComponent],
  templateUrl: './project-parent.component.html',
  styleUrl: './project-parent.component.scss',
})
export class ProjectComponent {

/**********************************************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************** SERVICES *******************************************************/
/**********************************************************************************************************************/

  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  private http: SpringAPIService = inject(SpringAPIService);
  private errorService = inject(APIErrorService);
  private projectService = inject(ProjectService)

/**********************************************************************************************************************/
/***************************************************** PROPERTIES *****************************************************/
/**********************************************************************************************************************/

  /* data properties */
  private projectID = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
  protected isDataLoaded: boolean = false;

  /* subjects */
  private ngUnsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  /* signal store */
  protected hasErrorSignal: Signal<boolean> = this.errorService.getHasError();
  protected projectSignal: Signal<AnyProjectDTO> = this.projectService.getProject()

/**********************************************************************************************************************/
/************************************************** LIFE-CYCLE HOOKS **************************************************/
/**********************************************************************************************************************/

  protected ngOnInit(){
    // if signal store is not upto date, get project, and set it to the store
    if(this.projectSignal()._id != this.projectID) {
      console.log(this.projectSignal()._id)
      console.log(this.projectID)
      console.log("about to get project via API")
      this.getProject()
    } else {
      console.log("signal store already has project")
      console.log(this.projectSignal()._id)
      console.log(this.projectID)
      this.isDataLoaded = true;
    }
  }
  protected ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe$.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe$.complete();
  }

/**********************************************************************************************************************/
/****************************************************** FUNCTIONS *****************************************************/
/**********************************************************************************************************************/

  // get project from API
  private getProject(): void {
    this.http.getProject(this.projectID)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))
    .subscribe(
      (projectObject) => {
        if (projectObject != undefined){
          this.projectService.setProject(projectObject)
          this.isDataLoaded = true;
        }
      }
    )
  }

}

/**********************************************************************************************************************/
/*************************************************** END OF ANGULAR ***************************************************/
/**********************************************************************************************************************/
```

**Here is the template:**

```
@defer(when isDataLoaded) {

  @if(!hasErrorSignal()){

    <!-- app header bar -->
    <app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>

    <!-- project navigation menu -->
    <app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>

    <!-- project page router -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  } @else {

    <p>Error in making Http request(s).</p>

  }

} @placeholder {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Initialising data fetch...</p>
  </div>

} @loading (minimum 250ms) {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  </div>

} @error {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Something went wrong!</p>
  </div>

}
```

**Strange behaviour**

Bizzarely, when I comment out `<router-outlet></router-outlet>,` from the template, the parent loads fine, and doesn't keep cycling through ngOnInit.

OR

When I comment out

```
<!-- app header bar -->
<app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>

<!-- project navigation menu -->
<app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>
```

but leave the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>,` in, then it also works.

Any ideas? Sorry I don't know how to use StackBlitz.

**UPDATE:**

if inside getProject I do this, I still get the infinite looping

```
private getProject(): void {
    console.log("test")
    this.isDataLoaded = true

  }
```

**UPDATE - 2**

What I've discovered:

ngOnInit Infinite loops stops when:

- include only, `<app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>` and `<app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>`
- include only, `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
- keep all three, but remove the deferrable view block.
- replace the deferrable view, with an if block resolves the issue
- It definitely looks like some change detection bug in Angular 17.3

**UPDATE - 3**

- Infact, ignoring ngOnInit entirely, and setting isDataLoaded = true, instead of false, on initialisation, also causes the repetitive loading of the components: `<app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>` and `<app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>`, when `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` is also there. (Commenting out `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, or commenting out `<app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>` and `<app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>`, but not `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, still resolves the issue - but then I don't have the three components I need)

**UPDATE STACKBLITZ**

Here is what I managed to put onto Stackblitz
All the code is there (though I have the issue on Angular 17.3)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-aeguwd?file=src%2Fproject-parent%2Fproject-parent.routes.ts

**UPDATE - DEFER BLOCK**

These, I discovered also work with no issues, components in separate defer blocks, or nested inside another, but it is far from ideal...

**separate**

```
@defer(when isDataLoaded) {
  <!-- app header bar -->
  <app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>
}

@defer(when isDataLoaded) {
  <!-- project navigation menu -->
  <app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>
}

@defer(when isDataLoaded) {

  @if(!hasErrorSignal()){

    <!-- project-parent page router -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  } @else {

    <p>Error in making Http request(s).</p>

  }

} @placeholder {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Initialising data fetch...</p>
  </div>

} @loading (minimum 250ms) {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  </div>

} @error {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Something went wrong!</p>
  </div>

}
```

**nested**

```
@defer(when isDataLoaded) {

  @if(!hasErrorSignal()){

    @defer {
      <!-- app header bar -->
      <app-header [project]="projectSignal()"></app-header>
    }

    @defer {
      <!-- project navigation menu -->
      <app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation>
    }

    <!-- project-parent page router -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  } @else {

    <p>Error in making Http request(s).</p>

  }

} @placeholder {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Initialising data fetch...</p>
  </div>

} @loading (minimum 250ms) {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Loading data...</p>
  </div>

} @error {

  <div class="fadeIn">
    <p>Something went wrong!</p>
  </div>

}
```

**UPDATE**

The angular team acknowledged this as a big. They fixed it in <24 hours, in version 17.3.2

Comment: We'll need a complete repro (via stackblitz for example) to understand what it hapenning.

Comment: The ngOnInit is executed when the component is showed. That's: If you have under a `@if(condition)` or in a `<router-outlet>`, each time the "condition becomes true" or when you navigate to the path.

Comment: I don't know stackblitz, but full code above

Comment: please setup a stackblitz repro if you expect some help

Comment: added to stackblitz. Not sure if you can see the code and replicate the issue

Comment: problem also reported to angular team here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/55036#issuecomment-2020749993